# Python Parsing fasta format to line-based sequence

Tags: python

I need a python script to parse fasta format to line-based sequence.

**I need to change this:**

```
>GeneID12345
ATTACATATACCATACC
CCATATTAATCCGAGGG
TTACCTATAGGTATACC
>GeneID12346
TTGATACCATATATCCC
ATATGCCCTATATTCCT
TTACCTATC
```

**To this:**

```
GeneID12345 ATTACATATACCATACCCCATATTAATCCGAGGGTTACCTATAGGTATACC
GeneID12346 TTGATACCATATATCCCATATGCCCTATATTCCTTTACCTATC
```

Comment: **Recommendation:** your question could include the code you currently have, so that we can help you improve it.

Comment: This is not how Stackoverflow works. What have you tried?

Comment: @Jean You actually just need to click the *“edited N minutes ago”* link ;)

Answer (score 3):

This will do the job:

```
import sys

sep=''
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith(">GeneID"):
            sys.stdout.write(sep+line.strip()+' ')
        else:
            sys.stdout.write(line.strip())
            sep='\n'
```

Run like `python parse_fasta.py input.fasta`.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not limited to `python` then a concise solution with `awk`:

```
$ awk 'NR>1&&/^>/{printf "\n"}{printf "%s",$0}/^>/{printf " "}' file
>GeneID12345 ATTACATATACCATACCCCATATTAATCCGAGGGTTACCTATAGGTATACC
>GeneID12346 TTGATACCATATATCCCATATGCCCTATATTCCTTTACCTATC
```

Comment: That would be the way to go, should python not be required.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = []
last = None
for line in f:
    if line.strip('ATCG') != '': # contains non-nucleobases, i.e. is an id
        if last: # save previous data
            data.append(last)
        last = line + ' '
    else:
        last += line
if last:
    data.append(last)

# now pretty-print
for gene in data:
    print(gene)
```

Results in:

```
GeneID12345 ATTACATATACCATACCCCATATTAATCCGAGGGTTACCTATAGGTATACC
GeneID12346 TTGATACCATATATCCCATATGCCCTATATTCCTTTACCTATC
```

This assumes that `f` is the file that contains the original data; i.e. the loop iterates over the lines of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Step #1: install [BioPython](http://biopython.org/wiki/Main_Page).  Don't waste time reinventing the wheel.  If you're working with FASTA files, you can write your own semifunctional parser, or you can use one that already exists, with tutorials and everything.

Step #2: well, actually, step #1 is mostly it.  Code:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

with open("example.fasta") as fp_in, open("newformat.txt", "w") as fp_out:
    for record in SeqIO.parse(fp_in, "fasta"):
        fp_out.write("{} {}\n".format(record.id, record.seq))
```

produces

```
~/coding$ cat newformat.txt 
GeneID12345 ATTACATATACCATACCCCATATTAATCCGAGGGTTACCTATAGGTATACC
GeneID12346 TTGATACCATATATCCCATATGCCCTATATTCCTTTACCTATC
```

More importantly, you get `SeqRecord` instances that are easy to manipulate and that will correctly pick up other information that might be stored in a more complicated example:

```
>>> record
SeqRecord(seq=Seq('TTGATACCATATATCCCATATGCCCTATATTCCTTTACCTATC',
SingleLetterAlphabet()), id='GeneID12346', name='GeneID12346', 
description='GeneID12346', dbxrefs=[])
```